# How to modularize/abstract away os.walkDir and os.walkDirRec - Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I wonder if it is possible with function pointers or macros or the like, to make the code below more modular, as in, not repeat the whole for loop, with the only difference being the `walkDirRec` vs `walkDir`.

I tried with function pointers and a macro, but did not manage to get either one working. (-> nim-noob)

```cpp
import os

proc containsFilesWithSuffix(dir: string, suffix: string, recursive: bool = true) : bool =
  if recursive:
    for file in os.walkDirRec(dir):
      if file.toLower().endsWith(suffix):
        return true
  else:
    for file in os.walkDir(dir):
      if file.toLower().endsWith(suffix):
        return true
  return false
```

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
import std/[os, strutils]

template anyOfIt*(sequence, predicate: untyped): bool =
  var result = false
  for it {.inject.} in sequence:
    if predicate:
      result = true
      break

  result


proc containsFilesWithSuffix(dir: string, suffix: string, recursive: bool = true) : bool =
  if recursive: anyOfIt(walkDirRec(dir), it.toLower.endsWith(suffix))
  else:         anyOfIt(walkDir(dir),    it.path.toLower.endsWith(suffix))
```

Something like that would work fine, though in this case I would just write a `for` loop anyway since it is easier to add more conditions/logic when I need it.

Comment: wow :O
indeed, that is a bit on the complex side. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version using templates:

```cpp
import os, strutils

template innerLoop(it, op: untyped): untyped =
  for file {.inject.} in it:
    if toLower(op).endsWith(suffix):
      return true

proc containsFilesWithSuffix(dir: string, suffix: string, recursive: bool = true) : bool =
  if recursive:
    innerLoop(walkDirRec(dir), file)
  else:
    innerLoop(walkDir(dir), file.path)
  return false
```

Answer (score 3):

I find the main problem here is that `walkDirRec` and `walkDir` are `{.inline.}` iterators and have different signatures. Only `{.closure.}` iterators can be passed around freely (according to [the manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#iterators-and-the-for-statement-firstminusclass-iterators)). One way or another you have to unify their signatures, doing `file` vs `file.path` or interfacing.

I'm leaving this here to show how you can assign iterators to a variable if their signatures match:

```cpp
import os, strutils

iterator walkRec(dir: string): string {.closure.} =
  for file in walkDirRec(dir):
    yield file

iterator walkDir(dir: string): string {.closure.} =
  for _, file in walkDir(dir):
    yield file

proc hasFile(dir, suffix: string, recursive: bool = true): bool =
  let iterFiles: iterator(dir: string): string =
    if recursive: walkRec else: walkDir

  for file in iterFiles(dir):
    if file.toLower().endsWith(suffix):
      return true
```

Now you can call the `hasFile` proc as follows:

```cpp
echo hasFile("path", ".exe")  # Find .exe files recursively at path
echo hasFile("path", ".exe", recursive=false)  # Same, but no recursion
```

Comment: +1 for readability and addressing the modularity/abstraction part of the question. However, I was confused at first by the assertion in the first sentence that {. inline.} can't be passed freely.  May I suggest an edit: "the walkDirRec and walkDir iterators are {.inline.}..." or some such clarification that this restriction is particular to iterators.

Comment: Better now? Feel free to edit the text as needed.

Comment: Thought that would be rude. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers are pretty much the same, this is just another variant that balances readability against reusability a bit differently.

One complexity comes from the fact that your code as written won't compile: `file.toLower` in the `walkDir` branch doesn't compile, due to the fact that `walkDir` doesn't yield a string, but a tuple, so your branches aren't as similar as you present.

In this version i elide that fact with a hacky template that makes `file.path` work for either branch, and reduce the noise of passing more variables by declaring the templates in the scope of the proc.

```cpp
import std/[os,strutils]
proc containsFilesWithsuffix(dir: string, suffix: string, recursive: bool = true): bool =
  
  template path(s:string): string = s # walkDir/walkDirRec compatibility
  
  template loopWith(walk):untyped =
    for file in walk(dir):
      if file.path.toLower.endsWith(suffix):
        return true
  
  if recursive: 
    loopWith(os.walkDirRec)
  else:
    loopWith(os.walkDir)
```